# How to load several instances of Unity3D WebGL on one web page?

Tags: javascript, html, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm looking for a way to have several instances of Unity3D running on one web page to display 3D models and interact with them.

Apparently, it [used to be possible](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/180124/embedding-multiple-webplayers.html) when Unity still supported the [Web Player](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1224686/view.html), but I can't find anything else regarding possibilities of doing this with the new WebGL.

From what I understand, the current way Unity3D works in WebGL revolves around a `canvas` HTML tag with a specific class (`emscripten`) and id (`canvas`). Moreover, one needs to define a JavaScript module, which acts as a global object initializing the UnityLoader.

I got all of that working quite simply with a unique canvas, but I'm struggling with adding extra canvas.

**EDIT :** gman suggested iframes, but I wonder if there wouldn't be a cleaner way.

Comment: You could try putting them in iframes

Comment: I'll try that out, but I'll leave the question open for other suggestions. I wish there was another way..